# How many combinations do I need to create to sample 90% of possbile combinations?

Tags: statistics, combinations

I am doing a molecular biology experiment. I have a set of 24 DNA sequences, and I am randomly pairing them together. So, there should be, I think 276 possible combinations (sum series from 1 to 23). But, how many combinations will I have to generate to have a 90% chance of generating all 276 of the possibilities? A direct answer is nice, but just pointing me to the right search topics would be sufficient. (And keep in mind that I have a PhD in chemistry but sadly have never taken a statistics class).

Comment: your question stem and the question title seems to convey different things, do you want to find out the number of random samples of pairs that you have to get in order to obtain 90% of the 276 combinations (or) the minimum number of times you need to sample so that you have 90% of chance of generating all 276 combinations

Comment: Sorry, my mathspeak isn't great. I probably shouldn't have used the word "sample." What I mean is, how many randomly generated pairs do I need to make in order to (statistically) guarantee I get 90% of the 276 possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 276 different combinations.

This is more of a combinatorics problem than Statistics.

In essence, you are asking how many times do I pick randomly, in order to guarantee 90% ( 249) distinct combinations.

That $N = 276\times 275\times 274\cdots\times\ 29\times 28$  That seems large.  But if you randomly draw two sequences this many number of times, you are guaranteed that you will obtain 249 different combinations of the 276. The rationale is the first pair has 276 no of ways to pick, the next draw will have 275 number of ways to pick one other than the 1st, and 274 ways to pick the third and so on until you have 28 remaining combinations to pick the distinct 249th.  Thus if you drew this many number of times(N), you are guaranteed 249 distinct combinations.

Regards

Satish